Sync Token is not generated on some calendars but the others in same API call with same Opt params returns Sync Token
I'm trying to do full sync first then do incremental sync using Sync token later. But the problem is that one of tester's calendar is not returning any sync token on first full sync attempt but weirdly other calendars work well and return sync token. I'm using thie OptParms:
 $optParams = [
            'timeMin' => Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->toISOString(),
            'timeMax' => $startTime->addDays(90)->endOfDay()->toISOString(),
            'singleEvents' => true,
            'fields' => 'items,nextSyncToken',
            'showHiddenInvitations' => true,
];

Also events I received were also not correct (missing some OOO events but just for this calendar only). Anything to look out for?
I tried checking the calendar list and its accessRole is owner as follows
{
"accessRole": "owner",
"backgroundColor": "#F691B2",
"colorId": "22",
"deleted": null,
"description": null,
"etag": ""171XXXXXXXX"",
"foregroundColor": "#000000",
"hidden": null,
"id": "dummy@gmail.com",
"kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
"location": null,
"primary": true,
"selected": true,
"summary": "dummy@gmail.com",
"summaryOverride": null,
"timeZone": "Asia/Singapore",
"defaultReminders": [
{
"method": "popup",
"minutes": 10
}
],
"notificationSettings": {
"notifications": [
{
"method": "email",
"type": "eventCreation"
},
{
"method": "email",
"type": "eventChange"
},
{
"method": "email",
"type": "eventCancellation"
},
{
"method": "email",
"type": "eventResponse"
}
]
},
"conferenceProperties": {
"allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
"hangoutsMeet"
]
}
}
